# Unity Getting a [SerializedField] private variable to appear in my custom Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get my `[SerializeField]` private boolean variable to show in the inspector through my Editor I have created.   I normally do something like :

```
myTarget.AutoFill = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(...)
```

if the variable was public but since I have it as 'private' do I lose the chance to use it in my `Options_Manager_Editor`?  Is there a way around this since I want to keep Encapsulation?  Would I have to change to using `OnGUI`, just make it public since another script is needed it or make a public method in my `Options_Manager` that has the code for my boolean `AutoFill` for customizing my inspector?

My Options_Manager code:

```
public class Options_Manager : MonoBehaviour {
    // Auto fill.
    [SerializeField] 
    private bool AutoFill;
}
```

My Options_Manager_Editor code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

[CanEditMultipleObjects]
[CustomEditor(typeof(Options_Manager))]
public class Options_Manager_Editor : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI(){
        // Grab the script.
        Options_Manager myTarget = target as Options_Manager;
        // Set the indentLevel to 0 as default (no indent).
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;
        // Update
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.Toggle(new GUIContent("Test Fill", "Test Fill Tooltip."), serializedObject.FindProperty("AutoFill").boolValue);
        // Apply
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just recently tried something but I am not sure if this can cause any problems down the road but if anyone can look at this and let me know that would be great.

My Options_Manager code:

```
public class Options_Manager : MonoBehaviour {
    // Auto fill.
    [SerializeField] 
    private bool _autoFill;

public bool AutoFill{
    get{
        return _autoFill;
    }
    set{
        _autoFill = value;
    }
}
}
```

My Options_Manager_Editor code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;

[CanEditMultipleObjects]
[CustomEditor(typeof(Options_Manager))]
public class Options_Manager_Editor : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI(){
        // Grab the script.
        Options_Manager myTarget = target as Options_Manager;
        // Set the indentLevel to 0 as default (no indent).
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;
        // Update
        serializedObject.Update();

        myTarget.AutoFill = EditorGUILayout.Toggle(new GUIContent("Auto Fill", "Test Tooltip"), serializedObject.FindProperty("_autoFill").boolValue);
        // Apply
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: note that `void OnValidate()` is an ***INCREDIBLY HANDY CALL*** which is almost undocumented by Unity. on the runtime side it's the only practical way to change something "during Play, if you change it in the inspector variable"

Comment: @JoeBlow I am not sure how that is going to help me in my situation.  Can you explain based on my post how OnValidate will be helpful?

Comment: It does not help you.  Sorry, I just noted that there for the benefit of anyone googling this topic. (A good use for "comments".)  Cheers!

Comment: Seen all caps bold style text in comments. Knew it would be @JoeBlow

Comment: **LOL** @UmairM  :)

Answer (score 1):

MyProjectNamespace.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace MyProjectNamespace
{
    [ CustomEditor( typeof( MyMonoBehaviour ) ) ]

    [ CanEditMultipleObjects ]

    public class MyMonoBehaviourInspector : Editor
    {
        #region Variables

        SerializedProperty _myBoolSP;

        MyMonoBehaviour _myMonoBehaviour;

        #endregion Variables

        #region Functions

        void OnEnable()
        {

            _myMonoBehaviour = serializedObject.targetObject as MyMonoBehaviour;

            _myBoolSP = serializedObject.FindProperty( "_myClass._myBool" );

            Debug.Log( "_myBoolSP = " + _myBoolSP.boolValue );

        }



        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            serializedObject.Update();

            _myBoolSP.boolValue = EditorGUILayout.Toggle( "A Boolean", _myBoolSP.boolValue );

            GUILayout.Label( _myMonoBehaviour.MyBoolValue() );

            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        #endregion Functions

    }

}
```

MyMonoBehaviour.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyProjectNamespace
{
    public class MyMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Variables

        [ SerializeField ] private MyClass _myClass;

        #endregion Variables

        #region Functions

        public string MyBoolValue()
        {
            return "The value of _myBool is " + _myClass.MyBool;
        }

        #endregion Functions

    }

}
```

MyClass.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyProjectNamespace
{
    [ System.Serializable ]

    public class MyClass
    {
        #region Variables

        [ SerializeField ] private bool _myBool;

        #endregion Variables

        #region Functions

        public bool MyBool
        {
            get{ return _myBool; }
        }

        #endregion Functions

    }

}
```

For future reference. Note that you can have private variables, you just need to use `[ SerializeField ]`,  (and `[ System.Serializable ]` for classes that don't extend MonoBehaviour). You probably won't need `using UnityEngine.UI` for editor classes.